# What's the best approach to defer class attribute initialization?

Tags: python, oop

I have the following OO use-case:

```
class SomeClass(object):

    def __init__(self, arg1):
        self.attr_now = arg1
        self.attr_later = None

    def compute(self):
        # do some lengthy computation ...
        self.attr_later = x # some result
        # continue work ...
```

Is this an ideal approach to defer initialization of attribute `attr_later` or is there a better way? What I see is the type unsafety of the `attr_later` as it may change type during the lifespan of the enclosing instance ...

Comment: The type of any attribute can change during its lifespan in python...:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are talking about the OO use case, I think you must know about the access modifications you can do to protect the attribute for its value and type.

Think of this

```
class SomeClass(object):

    def __init__(self, arg1):
        self.__attr_now = arg1
        self.__attr_later = None

    @property
    def attr_later(self):
        return self.__attr_later

    def compute(self):
        # do some lengthy computation ...
        self.__attr_later = x # some result
        # continue work ...
```

The instance variables can be prefixed with a `__` for making it private to that instance. So you are sure, the variable cannot be changed from outside.  More over, create a `property` for the variable, so that you can access the value from outside.

If you think, you want to set the value from outside, define a `setter` and control the incoming assignment - something like

```
@attr_later.setter
def attr_later(self, attr_val):
    if isinstance(attr_val,str):
        self.__attr_later = attr_val
    else:
        raise 
        # or do damage control
```

You are in control of your instance, if you properly encapsulate the properties. Hope this makes some sense

Comment: The duuble-leading underscore dioesn't actually prevent anything, it just mangles the name. This is actually almost never used, the canonical convention for implementation attribute is one single leading underscore (https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables)